# JTable AutoCreateSorter incorrect sorting?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a GUI that connects to a database and returns the results of a table to a JTable, however, when I click on the column that is named "ID"; the sorting goes like this:

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
2
20
200
...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to store `Integer` objects in the `TableMedel`, not Strings
2. You need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of your `TableModel` to return Integer.class, so the proper `Comparator` can be used.

Comment: This worked perfectly, but now i used to have a datetime column, now only the date shows without the time, how can i fix that?

Comment: @Abdane, one question per topic. If you ask another question make sure you post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. I have no idea what you might be doing. The default renderer will display the date/time when you add a Date to the TableModel.